# Java: why Thread.sleep() and yield() are static?

Tags: java, multithreading

Why `sleep()` and `yield()` methods are defined as `static` methods in `java.lang.Thread` `class`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The code would only execute when `someXThread` was executing, in which case telling `someYThread` to yield would be pointless. So since the only thread worth calling `yield` on is the current thread, they make the method `static` so you won't waste time trying to call `yield` on [some other thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/366656/java/java/sleep-yield-static).

Comment: Other threads are not necessarily yielded - if there are more than one processor (core), then they can be active. The true reason is that applying yield and sleep to other thread is unpredictable and dangerous, violating other threads' privacy.

Comment: The question is about why that method is static ??Its not about accessing other threads.And a good a point here so far :)

Answer (score 14):

This is because whenever you are calling these methods, those are applied on the same thread that is running.
   You can't tell another thread to perform some operation like, `sleep()` or `wait`. All the operation are performed on the thread which is being executed currently.

Comment: I think wait is not a static method, reason is wait and notify methods used for communication between two threads while sleep and static is used inside of the current thread.

Comment: No `wait` is not static, I meant to say that if you call wait method, then it causes current thread to stop until `notify` is called by other thread. You are right regarding communication between two threads

Comment: But you can only call `wait` on the current thread if you have taken the current thread's lock. `wait` and `sleep` are quite distinct.

Answer (score 6):

If you call the `yield` or `sleep` method, it applies to whichever thread is currently executing, rather than any specific thread - you don't have to specify which thread is currently running to free up the processor.

[similar thread in this forum](http://www.coderanch.com/t/366656/java/java/sleep-yield-static)

Answer (score 2):

The same reason is why stop() and suspend() methods are deprecated. Intrusion in thread's state from outside is dangerous and can cause unpredictable result. And if sleep is not static, for example, how do you think interruption from it will happen?

Answer (score 2):

They are static so that overriding concept can be avoided i.e.

When they are called with parent class reference to hold child class object like situation it implements Method Hiding concept and not overriding due to Static method nature, i.e parent class(here thread class) method will run which have the complete functionality of sleep and yield.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/goygW.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Both sleep and yield methods are native. To understand better from above answers I made two classes ClassA and ClassB with same static method. I invoked method of other class to check its behavior. So we can call other class' static method.
So may be there is other reason behind making sleep method static.

```
public class ClassA {

    public static void method(){
        System.out.println("Inside ClassA method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method();
        ClassB classb = new ClassB();
        classb.method();
    }
}

    public class ClassB {
    public static void method(){
        System.out.println("Inside ClassB method");
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to this party, (blame my parent :-))
I would like to answer this using proof by contradiction.
Let's say `sleep` method is not `static` so you can call sleep on any other thread object.

Let's say there are two threads, `thread A` and `thread B`. Now consider two possible scenarios in the context of `sleep` method, the same applies to `yield` as well.

1. System having single processor has only one thread active at a time, so if `thread A` calls `sleep` on `thread B` object i.e. `B.sleep()`, B is not in execution, as currently executing thread is `thread A`, so calling `sleep` on non-executing method is pointless.
2. A responsible programmer would never define `sleep` inside a `synchronized` block, or when a thread is holding a lock. But let's say `thread A` calls `sleep` method on `thread B` just when `thread B` is holding a lock(or inside a `synchronized` block), `thread B` would go to sleep holding lock which is totally undesirable.

These are just a few situations which forced jvm to not allowed thread to call sleep on another thread obect.